# Qutip on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, python-2.7, linux-mint, qutip

I try to transition from Ubuntu to Linux Mint on my new Laptop.
As I'm currently working on a project using QuTiP for simulations I want
it to work on Linux Mint as well. I followed the installation
route from the qutip page http://qutip.org/docs/3.1.0/installation.html#installation-on-ubuntu-linux which as far as ubuntu is concerned worked like a charm. But for Mint it is not working. I get the following error message, which I searched here but didn't get reasonable results.

> ImportError: Building module qutip.cy.spmatfuncs failed: ["CompileError: >command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1\n"]

which I'm not really sure what to make out of it, as I'm certainly have gcc installed, a x86 architecture with an intel i7 and linux installed :).

If somebody is facing the same problem or has an idea how to solve the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Greetings

Edit:

I'm now a bit unsure about my installed python as the first comment suggested. The package description goes as follows

> The following packages would be installed: libpython2.7-stdlib:i386, libjack0, libutempter0, libpython-stdlib:i386, xterm, libpython2.7-minimal:i386

(this is the installed package)

But I'm having a 64 bit system so I don't understand why this is installed by default on the Linux Mint 17.3 system. I'm also hesitating because
others warned me to mess with the existing python installation.

Comment: probably a problem with your installed python, I've just installed all and there is no error.

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know, I will try to reinstall python then.

Answer (score 0):

Download Anaconda from here:
https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Open bash in the folder that you have downloaded the install file in and write:

```
bash  installfile.sh
```

Open the terminal and write:

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

Hit enter.

```
conda update conda
```

Hit enter.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Hit enter.

```
conda install qutip
```

Hit enter.
It is ready!